# How to fix sticky footer? Flex or Grid is not working

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a website, and I'm facing the problem of coding a sticky footer that stays down if there is less content.

I've already tried using flex box and grid to code the sticky footer I need. I've tried many tutorials but nothing seems to be working. Here is a snippet of my html and css.

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
min-height: 100%;
flex-direction: column;
display: flex;
}

.footerdiv{
flex: 1 0 auto;
text-align: center;
padding: 60px 0;
}




</section>
    <section class="footer">
      <div class="footerdiv">
        <p>COPYRIGHT © 2019. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED. Design by<a 
id="name" href="X"> Akshat Mundra</a></p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a id="privacy" href="#">PRIVACY</a>
            <a id="contact" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply `flex: 1 0 auto` to the `<section>` that comes **before** the footer.

Note that you'll also want `margin: 0` on `<body>` so that there's no unnecessary vertical scrollbars when there's not enough content to span the full `height` of the page.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.footerdiv {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="content"></section>

<section class="footer">
  <div class="footerdiv">
    <p>COPYRIGHT © 2019. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED. Design by<a id="name" href="X"> Akshat Mundra</a></p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a id="privacy" href="#">PRIVACY</a>
        <a id="contact" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Note that each of the following rules that are required to make use of a fixed, sticky footer using the flexbox approach:

[image: Flex footer]

Comment: This doesn't create a sticky footer though  (I might have misunderstood what he's asking for). If body is higher than the viewport and there's scroll then the footer will be out of the screen.

Comment: I've tried this and the result hasn't changed. Here is my updated code:

Comment: I've fixed it. No need to worry. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the flex: 1 0 auto on the footerdiv class and just create/add this one instead:

```
.footer {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

So that the footer would automatically align at the bottom part of the page even if it has less content on it.

Check it on this codepen link
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YmexgW

Answer (score 0):

Stickiness cannot be achieved with flexbox or grid. You can do it with `position: fixed` though, like I've done [here](https://codepen.io/a-morn/pen/xvYLmv), or with `position: sticky`.

Also: use the `footer` tag for footers.

```css
footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: teal;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that the question was worded improperly, Mohrn. Simply put, I want to fix my footer to the bottom on my multipage website.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few answers before but for me only this code was good)

```html
<style>
.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
}
</style>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

another way to solve it

```html
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.main-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However, I've already tried the 2nd solution. I will try this again. The first solution is not intuitive. I am not sure why would this work? I will try this as well